# How to use .le() and .ge() when filtering pandas data frame columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is an example pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"first_column": ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7"],
        "second_column": ["cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2"],
        "third_column": [5, 1, 8, 3, 731, 189, 9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
     first_column second_column  third_column
0        item1          cat1             5
1        item2          cat1             1
2        item3          cat1             8
3        item4          cat2             3
4        item5          cat2           731
5        item6          cat2           189
6        item7          cat2             9
```

I would like to "filter" the third column based on 10 =< x =<1000.

If I do greater than or equal to 10, this is:

```
df['greater_than_ten'] = df.third_column.ge(10).astype(np.uint8)
```

If I do less than 1000, it is:

```
df['less_than_1K'] = df.third_column.le(1000).astype(np.uint8)
```

but I cannot do these operations simultaneously, i.e.

```
df['both'] = df.third_column.le(1000).ge(10).astype(np.uint8)
```

Nor could I try these operations sequentially.

How can I use `.ge()` and `.le()` together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`between()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) instead for your Series of interest.

```
df['both'] = df.third_column.between(10, 1000).astype(np.uint8)
```

Yielding

```
>>> df

  first_column second_column  third_column  both
0        item1          cat1             5     0
1        item2          cat1             1     0
2        item3          cat1             8     0
3        item4          cat2             3     0
4        item5          cat2           731     1
5        item6          cat2           189     1
6        item7          cat2             9     0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Separate question: how I could do this by second_column category, i.e. only do `df.third_column.between(10, 1000)` for `df.second_column=="cat1"`, etc. Is there a more algorithmic way to do this then manually specifying each category?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang In that case probably `eval` syntax, something like `df.eval('second_column == "cat1" and 10 <= third_column <= 1000')` if I understand you correctly. Sort of outside the scope of your original question though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&` to compound the conditions:

```
In [28]:
df['both'] = df['third_column'].ge(10) & df['third_column'].le(1000)
df

Out[28]:
  first_column second_column  third_column   both
0        item1          cat1             5  False
1        item2          cat1             1  False
2        item3          cat1             8  False
3        item4          cat2             3  False
4        item5          cat2           731   True
5        item6          cat2           189   True
6        item7          cat2             9  False
```

Comment: easy one buddy, easy one :D

Answer (score 2):

```
In [11]: df['both'] = df.eval("10 <= third_column <= 1000").astype(np.uint8)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  first_column second_column  third_column  both
0        item1          cat1             5     0
1        item2          cat1             1     0
2        item3          cat1             8     0
3        item4          cat2             3     0
4        item5          cat2           731     1
5        item6          cat2           189     1
6        item7          cat2             9     0
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [13]: df.eval("second_column in ['cat2'] and 10 <= third_column <= 1000").astype(np.uint8)
Out[13]:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
dtype: uint8
```

Comment: @MaxU This is great! Now, my only other concern is how I could do this by `second_column` category, i.e. only do `df.eval("10 <= third_column <= 1000")` for `df.second_column=="cat1"`, etc. Is there a more algorithmic way to do this then manually specifying each category?

Comment: @Noobie, i'm not sure that i understand you correctly... What do you mean saying "error prone"?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, please see update - is that what you want?

Comment: @MaxU That works, but I think I would have to do this for each category in `second_column`. This is a data frame of dozens of categorical values in `second_column`, e.g. `cat1`,  `cat1`,  `cat2`,  `cat3`,  `cat4`,  `cat5`...

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, could you provide a reproducible sample data set and a corresponding desired data set?

Comment: And maybe consider asking this in another question if you can't figure it out... this question is rather nicely scoped right now, but adding further questions to it will leave the existing answers a bit... out of place.

Comment: @Mitch Ok, I'll ask a separate question which fleshes this out somewhat.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Cheers :)